# Android - Different ways of playing video

Tags: android, mp4, android-videoview

I just came across the limitation of VideoView of not being able to play mp4 video files that are wider than 320 pixels. I was wondering how can we overcome these limitations. I am trying to make my app as forgiving as possible, so other than using VideoViews is there another way to play these mp4 videos?

Chris

Comment: I have seen this limitation talked about before, but I have had success in displaying a video 480px wide running on a Nexus One and Motorola Droid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am not aware of a 320px wide limit on `VideoView`, though I haven't tried it.

You can use `MediaPlayer` and a `SurfaceView` to play back videos. In fact, that's pretty much all `VideoView` is. Last I looked at the `VideoView` source code, it was only ~200 lines.

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/vidtry) that implements a video player using `MediaPlayer` and `SurfaceView`, with screen taps to bring up some pop-up panels (e.g., timeline).

Comment: I tried playing the video with MediaPlayer and SurfaceView, still no luck! Also, if VideoView is just an abstraction of MediaPlayer and SurfaceView, then wouldn't the limitation have come from there?

Comment: I have played videos wider than 320px using `MediaPlayer` and `SurfaceView`. So have millions of other people with Android devices, using the Gallery (which uses `VideoView`, as it turns out) or third-party video players. I suspect that you are having some other problem than a built-in "limitation of VideoView of not being able to play mp4 video files that are wider than 320 pixels".