# Sharing VideoView between two MediaPlayers not working

Tags: android, media-player, rtsp, android-videoview, surfaceholder

I have one main MediaPlayer which plays nicely an RTSP stream and I have used an AsyncTask to buffer the content of another stream. It achieves this. When I try to switch to the second stream, I can hear that the stream switched and it doesn't lag, but I only get sound. 
The SurfaceHolder holds a VideoView, it has been prepared, I registered it as Display for both
mediaplayers. 
When I switch streams, I stop the old MediaPlayer but the surface doesn't get destroyed, which is good, but it doesn't display my second video. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you supply your VideoView instantiation code and the code you use to switch out the MediaPlayers?

In any case, I doubt this will work well because the VideoView instantiates its own MediaPlayer and uses it to play media. (see [VideoView.java](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/VideoView.java))

You would probably need to switch out the VideoView itself, or build a replacement for the VideoView using your own subclass of SurfaceView.

Comment: VideoView instantiation is the standard one in the Android documentation, I attach it to a SurfaceHolder and then call setDisplay(mHolder) on my MediaPlayer. I understand what you say about the VideoView and its own mediaplayer, but how can I take advantage of the mediaplayer that is already prepared() and ready to start()? Should I instantiate 2 VideoViews and make the old VideoView invisible and my the new one associated to the second MediaPlayer visible?             Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Can you show me the link to the VideoView instantiation you're talking about? If you're using VideoView, then your code shouldn't mention MediaPlayer (except in some VideoView callbacks that supply a MediaPlayer to you). A good starting point for how to develop your own custom SurfaceView would be VideoView.java, changing it (or subclassing it) to switch out two different MediaPlayers in one view.

Comment: Please also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096273/what-are-the-difference-between-mediaplayer-and-videoview-for-android

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the answer. I realize now that for what I need, I should make a custom implementation of VideoView. The other answer pointed to that as well.