# Better way to play network .webm on Android?

Tags: android, webm

I am making an app that plays webm's that are located at an external network location (http://example.com/file.webm). Currently, I can play them using code like this:

```
String path = "http://example.com/file.webm";
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.loadUrl(path);
```

And it plays fine. However, I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this. Android supports .webm (VP8) video so are there any other internal API's that can handle this, giving me more control?

Comment: Why did you tag this question html5 and webview? If you want an html5 file in a WebView, your solution is the shortest one (if short is a definiton of elegant)

Comment: @rds .webm is a format for HTML5 video, however if this was a poor reason to tag is such I can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

A WebView is not optimal. Instead:

- Use the `VideoView` element in your layout
- or use a `SurfaceView` and a `MediaPlayer` that you control directly.

See also [What are the difference between MediaPlayer and VideoView for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4096273/what-are-the-difference-between-mediaplayer-and-videoview-for-android)